# Bootstrap 3 Navigation Javascripts Disabled

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, drop-down-menu, responsiveness

I started using bootstrap and had a very good experience with it.

Today when I was testing it, I understood that the navigation menu doesn't work when javascript is disabled. i.e. drop down menus don't work (i know that they cannot work without javascript but atleast some alternative should be there) and the menu is not at all accessible for mobile devices having javasript turned off.

I didn't find any resources which helped to fix this online. So, is there any way (if not fix drop down menus) make the menu work on mobile devices?

Or do I have to stop using bootstrap?

Comment: One possible way to make drop down menus work will be to make them pop-up on hover and link to some other page when clicked.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Comment: -Seram what about that link?

Comment: *Bootstrap's plugins don't fall back particularly gracefully when JavaScript is disabled. If you care about the user experience in this case, use <noscript> to explain the situation (and how to re-enable JavaScript) to your users, and/or add your own custom fallbacks.* You'll have to handle it with some css.

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10506 Go through the comments. Some suggested solutions are there.

Comment: are you absolutely certain you want to develop for people who have javascript disabled? it will add a lot to your overhead as a developer, especially if it is a small website.

Answer (score 0):

Most modern mobile devices should be able to support JavaScript. And it is the recommended way of doing responsive Web pages.

However you may be able to use css for this type of function by using a hover which will display a div that you've defined and hidden further up in the css

There is also css animations if you wish to have some sort of movement.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Comment: Well, if at all it is the recommended way there may be some people (0.0001% of total) who don't have javascript  supported in their mobile devices, what about them? Remember, its meant to be responsive so it should be accessible as well.

Comment: You can still use bootstrap for all of your styling needs but if you want to do "animations" you'll have to take the longer route of using custom css for that.